# With a +6 base attack bonus can I use armiger’s mark then a regular attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, actions, damage

I ask because I can make 2 attacks with a base attack bonus of +6 and, since [armiger's mark](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/classes/warder/#TOC-Armiger-s-Mark-Ex-) only requires I hit something and deal damage, it also requires an attack.  When I make an attack, can I only use armiger's mark due to it being a special ability?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. I edited this question a little. I hope that's okay. If it no longer asks what you want it to, please edit it further or rollback. Thank you for your participation and have fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The [armiger's mark](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/classes/warder/#TOC-Armiger-s-Mark-Ex-) is compatible with multiple attacks

The warder extraordinary ability [armiger's mark](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/path-of-war/classes/warder/#TOC-Armiger-s-Mark-Ex-), in part, says

> Whenever the warder attacks a foe in combat and inflict at least 1 point of damage, as a free action she may mark them as her foe (he may even mark a foe during an attack of opportunity and may make the free action to do so, even though it is not her turn) and attempt to continue to force them to engage the warder only.

Unlike the feat [Vital Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/vital-strike-combat-final/) that specifies an [attack action](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9pyy), the special ability armiger's mark specifies only that the warder must attack a foe and deal 1 point damage for the special ability to be used. And, unlike taking a move action or a standard action, taking a [free action](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Free-Actions) like this one doesn't interfere or limit the warder's other activities during the round.

Thus if a warder is capable of making multiple attacks during a [full attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Full-Attack) because of a high base attack bonus, after the first attack deals at least 1 point of damage the warder can take a free action to employ the special ability armiger's mark against that foe then continue the attack routine normally.

Comment: Interesting, I've never thought of it like that.  I find it strange that it doesn't say it's a free action.

Comment: @hijinksturtle …But it does: "[A]s a free action she may mark them…." Easy to miss, though.

Comment: Ahahaha, I guess I need to check my eyesight.  Thanks again!

Comment: I'll even add that Armiger's mark is not an attack per se, so the title "use armiger's mark and then a regular attack" is erroneous. You're actually making 2 attacks, and you can activate Armiger's mark on any one that deals 1 damage or more.

Comment: @Saryk I agree that the question's title shows a misunderstanding of how armiger's mark works, but I think the answer addresses that misunderstanding clearly enough. (The asker has already mentioned in comments on this answer that he missed that armiger's mark takes a free action to use.) However, if you think addressing the title directly is necessary for this answer to be good and complete, I *can* mention it… but it'll sort of feel like I'm piling on when it looks like the question stems from a simple oversight.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Oh no, the answer is clear enough :)